# Trigger for last inserted value

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

can anyone help me create a trigger that appends the last record from table Sensordata into Lastsensordata. I only want 1 value per ConnectionDeviceId and the value needs to be the last inserted one. (its going to be used to show in a gauge). I will link my sql script under.

```
CREATE TABLE Revpi (
revpiName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
revpiDateTimeCreated datetime NOT NULL,
revpiLocation varchar(150) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_revpiNavn PRIMARY KEY (revpiName)
);

CREATE TABLE Sensor (
sensorName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
revpiName varchar(100) NOT NULL,
sensorDateTimeCreated datetime NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_sensorNavn PRIMARY KEY (sensorName),
CONSTRAINT FK_revpiName FOREIGN KEY (revpiName) REFERENCES Revpi (revpiName)
);

CREATE TABLE Sensordata (
SensordataID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
data varchar (500),
ConnectionDeviceId varchar(500) NOT NULL,
EventProcessedUtcTime varchar(50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_sensorDataNavn PRIMARY KEY (SensordataID),
CONSTRAINT FK_sensorNavn FOREIGN KEY (ConnectionDeviceId) REFERENCES Sensor (sensorName)
);

CREATE TABLE Lastsensordata (
lastSensorNavn varchar(255) NOT NULL,
lastData varchar (500) NOT NULL,
LastTime varchar(50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_Lastsensordata PRIMARY KEY (lastSensorNavn),
CONSTRAINT FK_LastensordataSensordata FOREIGN KEY (lastSensorNavn) REFERENCES Sensordata (ConnectionDeviceId)
);
```

Comment: Generally , we wouldn't bother storing derived data

Comment: @Strawberry derived data is stored for all sorts of reasons, typically to improve performance of reporting. The entire concept of materialized views is based around storing derived data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_insert_sensordata 
AFTER INSERT ON Sensordata
FOR EACH ROW 
REPLACE INTO Lastsensordata VALUES (NEW.ConnectionDeviceId, NEW.`data`, NEW.EventProcessedUtcTime);
```

You will need to make the lastSensorNavn field unique. You should also fix the varchar size discrepancy between lastsensornavn and connectiondeviceid. The fixed table would look like:

```
CREATE TABLE Lastsensordata (
lastSensorNavn varchar(500) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
lastData varchar (500) NOT NULL,
LastTime varchar(50) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT PK_Lastsensordata PRIMARY KEY (lastSensorNavn),
CONSTRAINT FK_LastensordataSensordata FOREIGN KEY (lastSensorNavn) REFERENCES Sensordata (ConnectionDeviceId)
);
```